# I want link to go 50px below anchor when class name of the menu is not "xxx"

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I have a top menu inside a div that contains anchor links, like this:

```
 <div id="menu">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#item1">ITEM 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#item2">ITEM 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#item3">ITEM 3</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

When I scroll down the website, a class "wrapfixed" is automatically added on scroll by javascript to make the menu sticky, it becomes like this:

```
<div id="menu" class="wrapfixed">...</div>
```

I would like the link to go 50px below the anchor, when the class "wrapfixed" is NOT there.

how do you do that ?

Thank you

Comment: You will want to use Javascript to prevent the default link behaviou of `#` links. Then use `window.ScrollTo` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo  to scroll to the right part of the page

Comment: Hi Geoffery, I've provided an answer with working example below, please let me know if it works for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will want to to prevent the default link behavior of # links. Then check the if the links parent menu has the `wrapfixed` class, so you can set the extra padding. Before using [`window.ScrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to scroll the page to the right location.

Someting like this should work for you:

```js
function scrollToLinks(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    for (let i=0, len=links.length; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const index = event.target.href.indexOf('#');
        const selector = event.target.href.substring(index);
        const target = document.querySelector(selector);
        const box = target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const padding = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains('wrapfixed') ? 50 : 0;
        const y = box.top + padding;
        window.scrollTo(0, y);
      })
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", scrollToLinks);
```

And here is a working [demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/aronmarriott-smith/pen/BaWJQVQ)

Comment: Hi Aron, unfortunately I tried your code but it doesn't work :( I've set a log.console(padding) to see the value of padding. It gets the correct value, 50 if class contains "wrapfixed", and 0 otherwise, but it doesn't change anything to the scroll, it still goes to the same position. Live demo here: www.cosykombucha.fr

Comment: Ok, I think you need to subtract rather than add the padding. So this line: `const y = box.top + padding;` would change to `const y = window.scrollY + box.top - padding;`

Comment: No, still the same. I think the problem comes from the window.scrollTo(0, y); which has no effect for some reasons